# Android : how to create custom component

Tags: android, custom-component

Any one please guide me,

How to create a custom component in xml and java file

1. pass attributes from xml (this i somewhat completed)
2. how to pass attributes dynamically from new customClass() -- constructor method. -- i dont know how to implement this point

for Eg : I created a custom component with two textview as a single component. In xml i created two component by xml attributes. Now i want to create two new component by java code
by calling the constructor of my customClass.java I dont know how to create a new component dynamically from java code and how to display that in a view(Say a relative layout) Please help me provide any link or blog.

I have spent 1 week for this, But i didnt get any solution please help me

Answer (score 2):

its very simple:

in your layout xml file simply put the following lines of xml code:

```
<com.example.project.MyComponent
  android:id="@+id/myid"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Now, write a class named as your component:

```
public class MyComponent extends RelativeLayout {
  public MyComponent(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
    super(context,attr);
  }

  @Override
  public void onFinishInflate() {
    // this is the right point to do some things with View objects,
    // as example childs of THIS View object
  }
}
```

Remember the constructor: this constructor is needed by the LayoutInflater to
find your component. And, dont forget to call super(...) when required.

Comment: I am not sure if your custom tag will work but I know that this works: <com.example.project.MyComponent...></com.example.project.MyComponent>

Comment: my example extends a Relative layout - you dont MUST fill it with children like ImageViews,TextViews or other ;)

Comment: @Andreas Bf - Thanks for your response. public MyComponent(Context context, AttributeSet attr) this constructor is called when you are passing attr from your xml file. This part i completed. I want to create the component from java code(not from xml layout). like calling the constructor public MyComponent(Context context){...}I have to pass the values/attr from java code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling the constructor with context in its parameter and then setting the attributes with getter setters. You can find a good tutorial at [Android tech point](http://androidtechpoint.blogspot.com/2017/08/android-custom-views-with-examples.html)

```
MyComponent mycomponent = new MyComponent(context);
myComponent.setFirstTextView("text1");
myComponent.setSecondTextView("text2");
```

And then finally

```
layout.addView(myComponent);
```