# Ticker TextView in Notification Layout

Tags: android, notifications

Is there a way to make a `TextView` in a custom `Notification` layout look like a ticker? I'm using the following code to set `Notification` layout.

```
mNotificaionView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.status_bar);
mNotificaionView.setTextViewText(R.id.ticker, getLongText());
mNotification.contentView = mNotificaionView;
```

And the following attrs for `TextView` in status_bar.xml

```
android:singleLine="true" 
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

In fewer words, how do I create a ticker like `TextView` in a `RemoteViews` object?

Answer (score 1):

This should work, but only while your View has focus. 
See this answer, it may help you.
[Android notification Marquee not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512465/android-notification-marquee-not-working)

Comment: +1 That question says ' It's worth noting that there are some examples of Google Apps using marquee in their custom notifications'. Do you know which all?

Comment: Actually I've found out that the sample application that he talks about is HoneyCombGallery. But I made some tests and there's no notification "ticker-like" on it. I have both android tablet and smartphone for years, and I've never seen this on other apps, so I don't think it's possible...

Answer (score 1):

Look at Any.DO SmallWidget(4x1).

It's a ticker that fades text in and out. And it's an AppWidget. How does it work?

- Create an array of colors for the text, from the opaque, to the transparent and then to the opaque again.
- Create an alarm that when triggered it changes the text's color to the current color in the above array (the current index in the array will be saved).
- Make the alarm create a another one, to do the same for the next index in the array
- When the index is in the transparent part of the array - change the text to the next line we want to present
- When reaching the last index, we'll reset the array's index, and set an alarm to start the whole thing again. That alarm will be set to about 5 seconds from that moment (to give the user enough time to read the text)

The problem - battery consumption. All those alarms don't do well with the battery, but test it to see how bad is it first.

I never tried this on a notification bar widget, but since they are built with the same technique, this might work.

Good luck!